# UDK Kismet event using trigger used

Tags: triggers, game-engine, kismet-udk

i was trying to show an announcement in UDK using Unreal Kismet. I put the event "trigger used" (selecting my trigger) and when i press E i put an announcement which it has a text on it. The problem is that when i get close to my trigger and i press E(by default is E in UDK for the command "used) nothing happens!

Things to consider:

Aim to Interact is off.

Max trigger count is 0 (which is infinite)

The announcement has a text.

I have looking for an answer and i dont get what is wrong with my trigger. If someone could help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some game types don't show announcements.

I think that for sure UTGame does. So go to View>WorldInfo and check what game mode you are in.

Usually we make our own custom game types.

Comment: Confirmed, this worked for me.  Thanks for the tip!  (The "Interact text" still doesn't show up, unfortunately, so you have to make it clear what is and isn't a usable trigger.)  Incidentally, UDKGame apparently does *not* support usable triggers, at least not by default.  What is it in UTGame that enables this, so we don't necessarily have to inherit UTGame and all its glorious features?